How can I create a Higher-Order Component (HOC) in a Next.js/React app that checks permissions for all subcomponents before rendering them?
I'm trying to implement a global authorization strategy in my Next.js/React app where I can wrap the entire application in a HOC. The idea is to provide a configuration object (or fetch it from a backend) that defines the permissions for each component. The HOC should then recursively check all subcomponents before rendering them to ensure that only authorized components are visible to the user.
Here’s an example of what I’m aiming for:
// In app.tsx
<GlobalAuthorization config={permissionsConfig}>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</GlobalAuthorization>

The GlobalAuthorization HOC should traverse through all child components of Component and either allow them to render or replace them with a fallback (e.g., "Access Denied") based on the permissions specified in the permissionsConfig.
My Attempts:
I've seen solutions online that require you to add the HOC or use a hook in each component individually. However, my goal is to avoid modifying each component separately. Instead, I want to wrap the entire app in a single HOC that automatically handles this check for all components and their subcomponents.
I've tried various approaches to recursively traverse and wrap all child components, but I run into issues where only the top-level component is checked, and the nested components are either ignored or not logged correctly.
Additional Thoughts:
I've considered using middleware for this, but it seems like middleware would only apply to top-level components or routes, not to individual subcomponents.
Question:

How can I achieve this kind of authorization check for all
subcomponents in a Next.js/React app?
Is there a more effective
pattern or method for implementing this in React, especially when
considering complex component trees?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
